# Passing struct from array of structs to pthread_create

Tags: c++, struct, pthreads

I have created an array of structs.  I am attempting to pass one element in this array to a thread through pthread_create.  I am getting the following errors (they are for the 2 pthread_create calls I have in for loops):

```
/../a2/main.cpp|117|error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(serverDataStruct*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’|

/../a2/main.cpp|117|error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’|
```

I have looked all over and it seems that I have the correct syntax.  I will post my code below.  Can someone please help me?

```
struct serverDataStruct
{

};

struct clientDataStruct
{

};

void serverFunc(serverDataStruct *serverData);

void clientFunc(int *ticketNum);


struct serverDataStruct serverDataArray[MAX_NUM_SERVERS];   
struct clientDataStruct clientDataArray[MAX_NUM_CLIENTS]; 

int main (  )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numServers; i++) //create servers
    {
        pthread_create( &serverTID[i], NULL, serverFunc, (void*) &serverDataArray[i]); //PROBLEM LINE*****************************************************************

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++)
    {
        pthread_create( &clientTID[i], NULL, clientFunc, (void*) &clientDataArray[i]); //PROBLEM LINE*****************************************************************

    }
}


void *serverFunc(void *serverData)
{

}


void *clientFunc(void *clientData)
{

}
```

Comment: you should add 4 spaces to make it look better

Comment: You will get a better response from the awesome SO community if you (1) narrow your code down to 10 or so lines that give the same error and (2) use the `{}` button to format your code neatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are defined correctly, but your forward declarations are incorrect.

Change these two lines:

```
void serverFunc(serverDataStruct *serverData);
void clientFunc(int *ticketNum);
```

to match the function definitions:

```
void *serverFunc(void *serverData);
void *clientFunc(void *ticketNum);
```

Btw, please edit your question to remove all the unnecessary code :-)  And format it please :-)

Comment: k, I've removed most of the unrelated code.  and thanks, guess I needed a fresh set of eyes to see that mistake.  another question, but now I am getting an error of the following format:

Comment: woops, continuing that previous comment:
"undefined reference to `sem_open'", and I get this for all of my pthread functions (_create, _mutex, etc) and semaphore usages.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Robin: What headers are you including?  I would suggesting accepting this answer and opening a new question for the `sem_open` issue.  When you post that question, try not to post more than 10 lines of code.  It should be trivial to reproduce your error in 10-15 lines of code, and you might even solve your issue in the process.  My suggestion would be to copy your file and keep deleting things until you have a very small amount of code that gives you the problem still.

Comment: will do.  thanks Jared.  this was my first post so just learning the proper etiquette for posting.

Comment: @Robin: No need to apologize, we're here to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Pthread func::

```
void serverFunc(void * serverData){
struct clientDataStruct * client = (struct clientDataStruct *) serverData; // just as an //example
....
}
```

pthread_create call:

```
pthread_create( &serverTID[i], NULL, serverFunc, &serverDataArray[i]);
```

If you are using c++ code:
include this at the begining of you code after including all headers and namespaces , to prevent warnings:

extern "C"{void * serverFunc(void *);}